# ASP.NET 4 GridView filter for multiple strings using QueryExtender

Tags: asp.net, gridview, filtering

I have a GridView with an EntityDataSource.

I want to filter the rows at runtime using QueryExtender, by comparing it with multiple strings.

i.e., return only rows where a certain field is IN ('string1', 'string2', string3')

Can someone point me towards an answer? Thanks.

Edit: I already know how to do this for one string, read from a control at runtime. But I'm unable to find anything on Google that demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a `Enumerable<T>` you can define a `List<string>` containing the list of strings you are looking for and then write something like:

```
List<string> search = new List<string>();
            search.Add("string 1");
            search.Add("string 2");

            var query = from ex in YourEntities
                    where search.Contains(ex.Field)
                select ex;
```

`query` will have the items you are looking for.

**UPDATE**

I am not familiar with the QueryExtender control but [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537669.aspx) tutorial suggests that you do the following:

Add a CustomExpressionFilter between the opening and closing tags of the QueryExtender control:

```
<asp:CustomExpression OnQuerying="FilterByStrings"></asp:CustomExpression>
```

And then define in your code such method:

```
protected void FilterByStrings(object sender, CustomExpressionEventArgs e)
{
     List<string> search = new List<string>();
                search.Add("string 1");
                search.Add("string 2");

     e.Query = from ex in e.Query.Cast<YourEntity>()
               where search.Contains(ex.Field)
               select ex;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.

I should mention that i'm currently reading it from a hiddenfield value. 

Right now, I have:

<asp:QueryExtender ID ="QueryExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="MyEntityDataSource" >

<asp:SearchExpression DataFields="column1" SearchType="Contains">
  <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenField1">
</asp:SearchExpression>

</asp:QueryExtender>




I don't mind reading from a List instead of a control. But how would I include that List<string> value.

Apologize if this is a very basic question :-(

Comment: @colonel_px: I posted an update. I hope it's helpful; I've never used the QueryExtender before.

Comment: Thank you, Icarus.

I was just trying out something like that, using a method expression.

Will update once I find out if it works!

Comment: It worked!

The answer was to use MethodExpression and use a linq query to filter and return the rows.

Comment: @colonel_px excellent. And I imagine that FilterExpression would have worked too. The MSDN tutorial mentions that either method works for this case.

Comment: Thanks, marked as answer - as it appears your method would work.